# Cleaning a WPA wordlist

Tags: beginner, strings, file, bash

I have a short bash script that processes gigs and gigs of data.  I am looking for any improvements to make it faster.  This is my very first bash script so please be gentle. I am really only concerned about the `while` loop. The rest of it is fine I think. It's the `while` loop where the real work is done and could use the most enhancement.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script will clean a WPA wordlist
# It will read every line of the given file
#       Remove all whitespace except for newlines
#       Delete the line if it is less than 8 chars or greater than 63
# It will then exit with time of execution


IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator



startTime=$(date)       # start time of execution
fileToClean=$1          # this is the file we will be sanatizing, 1st cmd line arg
deletedlines=0          # number of lines that did not meet WPA PSK critera
validlines=0            # number of lines that were valid PSKs  and added to file


if [ -z $fileToClean ]; then #No file specified
        echo ""
        echo "No file specified!"
        echo ""
        exit -1
fi

if [ ! -f $fileToClean ]; then #File does not exist
        echo ""
        echo "File not found!"
        echo ""
        exit  -1
fi

#By this point I am assuming I entered a valid file and will begin cleaning
echo ""
echo 'Cleaning word list: ' $1
echo "Start Time: " $startTime
echo ""


while read line; do  #read every line in file and save to var line

        line="${line##*( )}"        # trim leading whitespace
        line="${line%%*( )}"        # trim trailing whitespace

        if [ ${#line} -ge 8 ] && [ ${#line} -le 63 ]; then     # if trimmedline length >= 8 && <= 63
                echo  $line >> $outputfile
                ((validlines++))
                continue
        fi

        ((deletedlines++))


done <$fileToClean


utime="$( TIMEFORMAT='%lU';time ( ls ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null )"  # this stores the executio time in the var utime

echo "Processing completed, it took" $utime "and $deletedlines were deleted."
echo $validlines "were added to the output file "$outputfile" as they were valid PSKs"
echo ""
```

Comment: The method you are using in your while loop you involves launching a process every time you want to trim lines. I guess this is going to be a bottleneck. You could try trimming the lines using bash-only constructs and see if this improves your throughput. See here for ideas (see the "trim" function suggestion) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable

Comment: Is there a reason to only use bash for text processing? I wrote a roughly equivalent loop in Python and ran it on a 100mb file of base64 data ("roughly equivalent" because I will write to the output file if the line starts with 'j') and it takes a total .5 seconds. The bash version is still running after 5 minutes.

Comment: I would like to stick to bash as I do not know any Python and feel using the right constructs I will be able to make a reasonable fast bash script for this task. I see how fast your method was +1 but I have a desire to stick to bash as this is also some what of a learning session for me.  Thanks for the idea landon!  @Brandin I will take your idea under consideration and see what you mean,  I will look into trying a different method and will report back.

Comment: The script is done running, what took hours to do a portion of the file took minutes using bash commands instead of launching external commands.  Can you create an answer with what you recommended.

Comment: I am sorry the file I used as test input was not 4gb it was 139921497 bytes( .1399gb ).  My mistake, but I was correct when I stated it took hours to run on the original script and only completed 4 millions lines and this time it completed all 14 million lines in just minutes.

Comment: I ended up using `awk` tto perform the task, it was very easy once I understood the `awk` syntax and thanks to the help of h.j.k  this is a much more elegant and effective solution.  Take the time to learn `awk` and use the correct tool, it will save you time and make you that much better at *nix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement can be reduced to just:

```
[[ ${#line} >= 8 && ${#line} <= 63 && $((++validLines)) > 0 ]] 
    && echo $line >> $outputfile || ((deletedlines++))
```

We use `bash`'s [`[[ ... ]]` shell keyword](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) to collate our conditions together. Helpfully, `[[ ... ]]` supports the use of `>=` and `<=`.

`[[ <something-to-test> ]] && <one-command-if-test-is-true> || <one-command-if-test-is-false>` is quite a useful (IMHO!) construct in `bash` for implementing a `if-then-else` logic. The only thing to note is that you can only specify one command each for both branches.

As such, we can 'inline' our increment of `validLines` and do an always `true` comparison to simplify our `if` branching, namely to either (`&&`) output the line to the output file, or (`||`) increment our `deletedLines`. Otherwise, it gets slightly longer due to the required use of [`{ ... }` compound command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/grouping_plain):

```
[[ ${#line} >= 8 && ${#line} <= 63 ]] 
    && { ((validLines++)); echo $line >> $outputfile; } || ((deletedlines++))
```

---

Now onto the other parts...

- `fileToClean` should be set as `fileToClean="$1"` in case the filename has spaces inside.
- Multi-line `echo` can be done as such:

  ```
  [ ! -f "$fileToClean" ] && cat<<M && exit -1

  Oh noes,
  We have a multi-line error message
  Telling user that the file is not a regular file.

  M
  ```
- Your way of checking the elapsed time should be done outside your script, using the `time` command. `time` can generate more (and probably more accurate) statistics about the 'performance' of your script and is readily available, hence the suggestion as opposed to manually calculating the value(s) yourself. :)

---

Now do you really need to do this in `bash`? Here's an `awk` one-liner (split into three for readability):

```
awk '{sub(/^[ ]+/,"");sub(/[ ]+$/,"")};
    length()>=8&&length()<=63{v++;print > "'"$outputfile"'" };
    END{print "Valid lines:",v"\nInvalid lines:",NR-v}' "$fileToClean"
```

1. Trim line.
2. If length matches, count the line and print to `"$outputfile"`.
3. At the end, print the summary for valid/invalid lines.

Comment: For me this is some dense coding, I am gonna have to work through all of this. For example I have never used the shell keyword, I have also never learned awk though it seems like I should.... When I have some time tomorrow I will work through all this.  Though it seems elegant and effective. +1 and probably accepted

Comment: Think of `[[` as a super `[`... ;)

Comment: huh interesting and useful too. Why the effort to inline the increment operator?  Is it just to make the assembly that much simpler and run that much faster?  Also what is wrong with timing it in that fashion? Just curious

Comment: Also maybe I should edit my answer but I now need to make sure to delete non-printable characters, it needs to be valid UTF-8 and nothing else.  Any hints that would be fast?

Comment: See my edit. :)

Comment: That is bad ass!  Is that just some syntax sugar or is it just a nice side effect of the natural structure of the language?

Comment: @Dylan this might be helpful: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: @Dylan and this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: Ok so it is a keyword not a command, that answered what I was looking for.  I am gonna read over both of those for sure. I am just trying to suck up everything I can right now.  Learning bash, python and mongo all day so I am spent.  But I will get back on it tomorrow and like I said I am sure I will be accepting your answer! Thank you that is great!

Comment: That awk statement was FAST!!!!!  Guess I need to quit fighting and just learn awk... Before I dive into it is it easy enough to remove non UTF-8 characters using awk or am i wasting my time.  Answer accepted!

Comment: I don't have much experience dealing with non-UTF-8 characters, but maybe this will give you a start? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760493/using-special-characters-in-a-string-argument-to-the-awk-match-function-current

Comment: I've spent the last couple hours on an awk tutorial. Not quite ready for that but I'll check it out. Thanks for all the help! Is been perfect!

Comment: It is amazing how powerful `awk` really is.  It is basically C without having to worry about a lot of the details with the language....  Thanks again